# How to increment only one value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to only increment the score in one box but it gets incremented in 2 places.
my code:

```
var homescore = document.getElementById('home-score')
var guestscore = document.getElementById('guest-score')

var i = 0; 
function add1() {           
    i++;       
    homescore.innerHTML = i
}

var i = 0
function add2() {
    i += 2
    homescore.innerHTML = i
}


var i = 0
function add3() {
    i += 3
    homescore.innerHTML = i
}

var i = 0; 
function add1g() {           
    i++;       
    guestscore.innerHTML = i
}

var i = 0
function add2g() {
    i += 2
    guestscore.innerHTML = i
}


var i = 0
function add3g() {
    i += 3
    guestscore.innerHTML = i
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BasketBall Score Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-side">
        <h1 class="left-title">HOME</h1>
        <br />
        <h1 class="home-score" id="home-score">0</h1>
        <button id="add1" onclick="add1()">+1</button>
        <button id="add2" onclick="add2()">+2</button>
        <button id="add3" onclick="add3()">+3</button>
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
        <h1 class="right-title">GUEST</h1>
        <br />
        <h1 class="guest-score" id="guest-score">0</h1>
        <button id="add1" onclick="add1g()">+1</button>
        <button id="add2" onclick="add2g()">+2</button>
        <button id="add3" onclick="add3g()">+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

FOr example, if I clicked the `+1` button in the home and incremented it to 9. And then after that, I  click `+1` in guest it shows 10 in the guest.
I want different values for each box. If I click `+1` in HOME it should increment to 1 and then if I clicked +1 in guest it should increment to 1 not 2. And If possible tell me a shorter way to write this code. THANKS

Comment: Don't use the same `i` variable for all of them

Comment: SHould I have different variables for all the i 's?

Comment: @Aaqil for each type you have a different variable so that it will not conflict with other type for ex - add2 should use variable i, add3 should use variable j and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of things: I would advise to avoid using `var`. Use `let` or `const` instead. [Why?](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

Declaring same variable again assigns a new value to that variable, removing its reference (or relationship) to the data it referred to previously.

[Declaring variables in JS](https://javascript.info/variables)

[Primitives vs Reference data types](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/primitive-vs-reference-data-types-in-javascript/)

Below I've refactored your code. You can try it out.

script.js file:

```
const homescore = document.getElementById("home-score");
const guestscore = document.getElementById("guest-score");

let homescoreCount = 0;
function add(num) {
  homescoreCount += num;
  homescore.innerHTML = homescoreCount;
}

let guestscoreCount = 0;
function addG(num) {
  guestscoreCount += num;
  guestscore.innerHTML = guestscoreCount;
}
```

You'd change the way function is called in your HTML as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>BasketBall Score Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left-side">
        <h1 class="left-title">HOME</h1>
        <br />
        <h1 class="home-score" id="home-score">0</h1>
        <button id="add1" onclick="add(1)">+1</button>
        <button id="add2" onclick="add(2)">+2</button>
        <button id="add3" onclick="add(3)">+3</button>
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
        <h1 class="right-title">GUEST</h1>
        <br />
        <h1 class="guest-score" id="guest-score">0</h1>
        <button id="add1" onclick="addG(1)">+1</button>
        <button id="add2" onclick="addG(2)">+2</button>
        <button id="add3" onclick="addG(3)">+3</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps. Don't be afraid to ask questions, and more importantly keep learning.

Comment: Can I know how can I make a button and reset the value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
var i = 0; 
function add1() {           
i++;       
homescore.innerHTML = i
}
```

Try to use,

```
var i = 0; 
function add1() {           
i += 1;       
homescore.innerHTML = i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a quirky minimalist solution, here it is:

```js
document.querySelector(".container").onclick=ev=>{
 let d=ev.target.closest(".right-side,.left-side")?.querySelector("h1[class$=score]")
 if (d) {
  d.textContent=+d.textContent+(+ev.target.textContent)
 } else if (ev.target.tagName=="BUTTON") // reset all
  document.querySelectorAll("h1[class$=score]").forEach(h=>h.textContent="0");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-side">
    <h1 class="left-title">HOME</h1>
    <br />
    <h1 class="home-score" id="home-score">0</h1>
    <button>-1</button>
    <button>+1</button>
    <button>+2</button>
    <button>+3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <h1 class="right-title">GUEST</h1>
    <br>
    <h1 class="guest-score" id="guest-score">0</h1>
    <button>-1</button>
    <button>+1</button>
    <button>+2</button>
    <button>+3</button>
  </div><br>
<button>reset all scores</button>
</div>
```